# What size versions are needed to accommodate full-window images for web sites?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, responsive-design

We want to have "pages" where the background image takes up the full width and height (the user will click an arrow and the full page will move up/down). Obviously, we don't want to get weird stretching on the images.

Is the best practice to have different size ratio versions of the image (e.g. 16:9, 4:3, etc) to accommodate different screens or do we simply stretch like this:

1. If it needs to be stretched to reach the left/right side (but is then too tall) we cut off the bottom of the image
2. If it's too short so it needs to be stretched to reach the top/bottom, then we cut off the left/right because it's too wide

What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: if you are using background-image css then you can use "cover" on background-size and it will auto resize the image to fit your container

Comment: @Liquidchrome yes, but it will stretch the image. With a photo, if the ratio of width-to-height is different for the browser window, it will look odd

Comment: if you set `background-size` to `cover` your image ratio is maintained, it doesn't do any stretching, just part of the image will disappear. How you set the `background-position` will determine which part of the image disappears. Check out this article on css tricks, may help: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/. Or consider reading up on the different css `background` properties https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: @JustinL. Thank you, I did not know that. That works!